# Key becomes invisible in pm3d gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using following code to draw a graph in gnuplot using pm3d map:

```
set pm3d map
set pm3d corners2color c1
spl 'patternD0pt02.dat' title "(a)"
```

But when the plot is generated, the title "(a)", which otherwise should have appeared in the top right corner, becomes invisible (or hides behind the plot). Is there any way to make this key/title visible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the title is hidden behind the surface and there is no option `set key front`. This is a bug in 4.6. and is fixed in 5.0.

You can workaround by placing a normal label, since the title of a pm3d plot doesn't plot a sample item. Putting a white rectangle behind the lable is a bit tricky:

```
set label center at graph 0.95,0.95 front '(a)'
set object rectangle front at graph 0.95,0.95 size char 5,2 fc rgb 'white' fillstyle solid noborder
```

A full, working example is:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600
set output 'foobar.png'

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
set samples 20
set isosamples 20

set pm3d map

set label center at graph 0.95,0.95 front '(a)'
set object rectangle front at graph 0.95,0.95 size char 5,2 fc rgb 'white' fillstyle solid noborder
splot '++' using 1:2:1
```

The result with 4.6.4 is:

[image]

Comment: Ah.. I see.. though I would have liked to keep background of the label white, this is not less for me. Anyway..please tell me if I can make small part around that label white. Also, what does that 1 signify in 'set label 1'?

Comment: The `1` is the tag of the label. With this you could later remove only this label with `unset label 1`, or overwrite the label content with `set label 1 'foobar'` which would keep the position of the previous `label 1`. Otherwise you don't need it. To have a white background for your key, you can use `set key opaque` and then adjust the position of the label to overlap with this region. Otherwise you would need to place a white rectangle behind the label, which is some fiddling. Note, that the upcoming 5.0 release knows `set label boxed` which simplifies this. I'll report the bug.