# gnuplot dgrid3d view map does not show the key

Tags: key, label, gnuplot, colormap

I am producing a colour map plot with gnuplot in this way:

```
set term png
set key on samplen 0.5 textcolor rgb "red"
unset grid
set xrange [-1.01:1.01]
set yrange [-1.01:1.01]
set xlabel "{/Symbol d}n"
set ylabel "j"
set zrange [0:3.5]
set cbrange [0:3.5]
set view map
set dgrid3d 16,16 gauss 0.003,0.003
set hidden3d
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set palette rgbformulae 23,22,21
unset xtics
unset ytics
set xtics border -1,1,1
set ytics border -1,1,1
set cbtics border 0,1,3.5
set format cb "%g"
set output "out.png"
splot "file.txt" u 1:2:3 w pm3d t "L 13"
```

But the label "L 13" does not appear, I cannot understand why.
Any idea about it?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't know which gnuplot version you gave, but check http://stackoverflow.com/q/23939317/2604213

Comment: thank you very much